# GRASS GIS Addon Installation Windows 10 Problem

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I know there are some very similar questions regarding this topic:
[GRASS GIS addon "extension not found"; could the problem be with the GRASS Addons server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262210/grass-gis-addon-extension-not-found-could-the-problem-be-with-the-grass-addon/329662#329662)

but so far nobody has found a proper solution it seems. I am trying to install r.stream.distance (and other) addons but not with Grass 7.6 or 7.8 i get any success. I tried to run a different g.extensions script (as suggested in the question mentioned above) and the addon seems to install but then there are alwas problems in running the addon, specifically:
[image]

Comment: That's unexpected, since it is there http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass76/x86_64/addons/latest/ --> r.stream.distance.zip - I try to notify the Windows addon maintainer

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking GRASS 7.6 Windows Addons are still not operational (in the term of daily builds), last build dates back to Sep 2019. Consider switching to GRASS 7.8 or wait for 7.6.2. Now back to your question, I tested r.stream.distance on my Windows 10 machine and it worked (I was able to install r.stream.distance in GRASS 7.6.1 and open GUI dialog).

Please try to reinstall r.stream.distance addons and let us know.